# Dax-medium font will only work in safari - why are other browsers not rendering?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to use the dax-medium font but it is only rendering in safari. Why won't it work in other browsers? Here is my css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'daxmedium';
src: url('http://www.almoproav.com/App_Style/css/fonts/dax-medium-webfont.eot');
src: url('http://www.almoproav.com/App_Style/css/fonts/dax-medium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('http://www.almoproav.com/App_Style/css/fonts/dax-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('http://www.almoproav.com/App_Style/css/fonts/dax-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('http://www.almoproav.com/App_Style/css/fonts/dax-medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('http://www.almoproav.com/App_Style/css/fonts/dax-medium-webfont.svg#daxmedium') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first try on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learningloop/31j4830s/6/) failed, with following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource 
at http://www.almoproav.com/App_Style/css/fonts/dax-medium-webfont.ttf. 
(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

Later i uploaded the font to my sample [git project](https://github.com/learningloop/learningloop) and verified this [hosted](http://dock.ninja/static/learningloop/learningloop/index.html) link in Firefox & chrome and it works fine there. This didn't work in IE11.